# Children of parent maintain current position after parent removed?

Tags: parent

I have several objects set as children of a parent object. Whenever I remove the parent object (an empty in this case), the position of all of the children are skewed. I'm guessing that this is do to them being moved after the parent relationship was made? I'm looking for a way for all of the child objects to maintain their current positions after the parent has been removed. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select the children and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, where 3 options will be presented in a popup menu. The option to *Clear and Keep Transform* will clear the parent of the children and allow them to keep their current scale, position, and rotation.