# How do unparent my model from plain axis(object) while keeping rotation

Tags: modeling, transforms

There is a empty plain axis that is like parent of my model(s), id like to unparent the model(s) from the empty plain axis but if i delete the plain axis my model gets rotated 180, which is something i cant allow. I need to get the model inside the empty plain axes out whitout it changing model(s) rotation(esentially keeping the same rotation and xyz placement it has inside the plain axis object, aka unparent cant not move the model(s) or worse to rotate the model(s)...

[image]

Comment: ALT + P > Clear and Keep Transformation.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56214/children-of-parent-maintain-current-position-after-parent-removed

Comment: Ok thx, how do i claim it as answered?

Comment: I added my answer to the "Answer" section. You can check that off if you'd like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose " and Keep Transformation" from the drop down menu.